# Force Balance Tags not working

Tags: theme-development, tags, the-content, formatting

I am trying to shorten my `the_content()` word count to 200 while retaining the html formatting as well as the shortcodes. I am pretty close but for some reason, I cannot get force balance tags or balanceTags() to work as intended.

The code I am using is the following

```
$content = html_entity_decode(wp_trim_words(htmlentities(get_the_content()), 200));
echo force_balance_tags(do_shortcode($content));
```

If I break the content at 300, its fine, but that is only because it doesnt cut at an html tag. specifically at 200 it is cutting at `target="_blank"` and not closing the `a` tag. When i run the balance tags functions, it seemingly does nothing.

How do I get the content, make sure it keeps the formatting and short codes, AND balances the tags regardless of where I end it.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.